# Get space related information from multiple servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, diskspace

I need to create an SSRS report that would display space related information for all of our servers and associated databases.

Is there a way to create a stored procedure that would loop through all servers and write space information to a temp table?

Or is it possible to do it via SSRS report where based on parameter chosen, it connects to a specific data source, and gets the space related information?

Comment: I ended up doing this in SSRS.  Had to get bit creating, but was able to do it!  Anyone need help, let me know and I'll post what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I need to create an SSRS report that would display space related information for all of our servers and associated databases. Is there a way to create a stored procedure that would loop through all servers and write space information to a temp table?**

It would be a bit cumbersome, however you can make use of linked servers and dynamic SQL to loop each server and store results in a base table. You can then use the base table as a datasource for your SSRS report.

A better way to do it would be to use a powershell script to loop through each database server, store the results in your database reporting server and utilize an SSRS datasource to access the records from the reporting server.

**Or is it possible to do it via SSRS report where based on parameter chosen, it connects to a specific data source, and gets the space related information?**

You can make use of an SSRS dynamic datasource to connect to a specific data source and execute SQL to get space related information - however this would only return capacity information on one server. Here is how to work with dynamic datasources:
http://blog.rdx.com/blog/dba_tips/2014/02/creating-dynamic-data-sources-in-ssrs

Best way to do it as above would be to have a single central reporting server as a central data store, which queries each Database Server and stores the data. You can then point your report to the central datasource